Can we combine lines 0-32 into a single row with keypoints, adding timestamps divisible by 33 (number of keypoints)?
Here the my output from my code
code's output
There is a 33 keypoint, which consists of
body_pose = ['NOSE', 'LEFT_EYE_INNER', 'LEFT_EYE', 'LEFT_EYE_OUTER', 'RIGHT_EYE_INNER', 'RIGHT_EYE', 'RIGHT_EYE_OUTER', 'LEFT_EAR', 'RIGHT_EAR', 'MOUTH_LEFT', 'MOUTH_RIGHT',
              'LEFT_SHOULDER', 'RIGHT_SHOULDER', 'LEFT_ELBOW', 'RIGHT_ELBOW', 'LEFT_WRIST', 'RIGHT_WRIST', 'LEFT_PINKY', 'RIGHT_PINKY', 'LEFT_INDEX', 'RIGHT_INDEX', 'LEFT_THUMB',
              'RIGHT_THUMB', 'LEFT_HIP', 'RIGHT_HIP', 'LEFT_KNEE', 'RIGHT_KNEE', 'LEFT_ANKLE', 'RIGHT_ANKLE', 'LEFT_HEEL', 'RIGHT_HEEL', 'LEFT_FOOT_INDEX', 'RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX']

The problem is that the names NOSE_x, NOSE_y, and NOSE_z are stored on row 0 -> correct
But the next cycle LEFT_EYE_INNER_x, LEFT_EYE_INNER_y, and LEFT_EYE_INNER_z are stored on row 1 -> wrong because they should be stored on row 0 in number 0,
and so on
how to combine it into one row?
Here, my code for append data and save it in excel format
    def save_data_to_excel(self):
        data_dict = {pose_type: [] for pose_type in ['pose', 'right_hand', 'left_hand']}
        for pose_type, pose_data in self.alldata:
            for idx, (key, value) in enumerate(pose_data.items()):
                # Append timestamp along with position data
                timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
                key_suffix = ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
                data_dict[pose_type].append({**{'Number': idx, 'Timestamp': timestamp}, **{f'{key}_{key_suffix[i]}': val for i, val in enumerate(value)}})
                #data_row = [idx, timestamp] + [{f'{key}_{key_suffix[i]}': val for i, val in enumerate(value)}]
                #data_dict[pose_type].append(data_row)

        with pd.ExcelWriter('koordinat.xlsx') as writer:
            for pose_type, data in data_dict.items():
                df = pd.DataFrame(data)
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=pose_type, index=False)

My expectation's output is that the 33 keypoints and and timestamps divisible by 33 are stored at number 0, number 1, number 2, and so on in each one row
the link for accessing a excel file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12taz4_8HV8865D80kkEHqEFw3U6o4pZp/edit?rtpof=true&sd=true

It would be super helpful to include a text version of a few dozen rows of your data in a csv style format so that people could try to help without reentering all that data by hand. Having said that, process your rows one at a time. When you get a value for Nose_X that is a signal that you have started a new row in your result. Accumulate data into this new result until you reach the end condition ora a new start condition.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12taz4_8HV8865D80kkEHqEFw3U6o4pZp/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=101010652332933527093&rtpof=true&sd=true

I provided the link for excel file

Welcome to SO! As recommended in [ask], please [edit] your post so as to share some input data as text, not images. More tips in [mre] and specifically for Python/Pandas: How to make good reproducible pandas examples. suggestion: Post only a representative portion of your data + the corresponding expected output.

I would use the csv package and read the rows one at a time accumulating results. When you see a row with data for NOSE_x that is a signal that you are starting a new final result row and that allows you to begin merging data for the final result row.
Note that this example uses io.StringIO() to simulate open() and I will print the results rather than write them to a file. I think you can likely handle reading and writing the files.
import io ## we will simulate open with io.StringIO()
import csv

raw_data = """
"Timestamp","NOSE_x","NOSE_y","NOSE_z","MOUTH_x","MOUTH_y","MOUTH_z"
1.1,1,2,3,,,
2.2,,,,4,5,6
10.1,10,20,30,,,
20.2,,,,40,50,60
""".strip()

results = []
with io.StringIO(raw_data) as file_in:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_in)
    for row in reader:
        if row.get("NOSE_x"): # we have a starting result row
            result = {}

        for key, value in row.items():
            if value:
                result[key] = value

        if row.get("MOUTH_z"): # we have a final result row
            results.append(result)

for result in results:
    print(result)

That should give you:
{'Timestamp': '2.2', 'NOSE_x': '1', 'NOSE_y': '2', 'NOSE_z': '3', 'MOUTH_x': '4', 'MOUTH_y': '5', 'MOUTH_z': '6'}
{'Timestamp': '20.2', 'NOSE_x': '10', 'NOSE_y': '20', 'NOSE_z': '30', 'MOUTH_x': '40', 'MOUTH_y': '50', 'MOUTH_z': '60'}


Hi JonSG, good solution. I exported the linked Google Sheet to CSV and tried your script. For the real data, the start key needs to be NOSE_X and the end key RIGHT_FOOT_INDEX_Z.

sure, rather than read an excel file that might have a macro (not that you are doing anything nefarious) I just created a small toy example to illustrate the concept I might use.

JonSG's answer is good. Just for fun, you can also get what you want without knowing/specifying the column names. Instead, you can use your knowledge that groups of 3 columns, what I'll call an XYZ triplet, shift 3 columns to the right for every row, repeats for 33 rows; and then the whole cycle repeats.
I don't know what "timestamps divisible by 33" means. I'll show how you can pick the first or last timestamp in a group of 33 rows.
My solution requires specifying up front:

the number of fields in a triplet
the number of rows (group-size) that make up a complete record
the index of the first triplet (begin)
the index of the timestamp column

To develop this idea, I reduced your data to this toy sample:
No, TS, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2
 0, 11, a,  a,  a,  ,   ,
 1, 12, ,   ,   ,   b,  b,  b
 2, 13, c,  c,  c,  ,   ,
 3, 14, ,   ,   ,   d,  d,  d

so my initial parameters look like:
TRIPLET = 3  # number of fields in an "XYZ triplet"
GROUPS = 2   # number of triplet rows
BEGIN = 2    # 0-based column index for start of triplets
TS_IDX = 1   # 0-based column index for timestamp field

I create the results list to accumulate each (final) result row, open the CSV, get the header, and then assert the header has enough columns based on my initial params:
results: list[list[str]] = []
with open("input_mine.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)

    # header is made up of BEG-number leading columns plus GROUPS-number triplet columns
    assert len(header) == BEGIN + (GROUPS * TRIPLET)
    ...

I then append the header (starting at the timestamp column) to the results list, and set up the intermediate result row, and an offset.
The offset starts at the index of the first triplet column and will advance in steps of 3 columns for the next row. The result row gets 3 columns of data from the current row. Then offset advances to the next 3 columns, for the next row.
If the row is the last row in a group, the timestamp and the complete result row are appended to results, the result row resets, and offset resets to the first triplet column.
    ...
    results.append(header[TS_IDX:])

    result_row: list[str] = []
    offset = BEGIN
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        result_row.extend(row[offset : offset + TRIPLET])
        offset += TRIPLET

        if i % GROUPS == 0:
            results.append([row[TS_IDX]] + result_row)
            result_row = []
            offset = BEGIN

From that simple sample, I get:
TS, x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2
12, a,  a,  a,  b,  b,  b
14, c,  c,  c,  d,  d,  d

If I wanted the first timestamp, I'd change the loop to:
    ...
        if (i - 1) % GROUPS == 0:
            result_row.append(row[TS_IDX])

        result_row.extend(row[offset : offset + TRIPLET])
        offset += TRIPLET

        if i % GROUPS == 0:
            results.append(result_row)
            result_row = []
            offset = BEGIN

I also exported your Google Sheet as a CSV, and ran this against it:
import csv
import sys

TRIPLET = 3  # number of fields in an "XYZ triplet"
GROUPS = 33  # number of rows that make a complete record
BEGIN = 2    # 0-based column index for start of triplets
TS_IDX = 1   # 0-based column index for timestamp field

results: list[list[str]] = []
with open("input_op.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)

    assert len(header) == BEGIN + (GROUPS * TRIPLET)

    results.append(header[TS_IDX:])

    result_row: list[str] = []
    offset = BEGIN
    for i, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
        if (i - 1) % GROUPS == 0:
            result_row.append(row[TS_IDX])

        result_row.extend(row[offset : offset + TRIPLET])
        offset += TRIPLET

        if i % GROUPS == 0:
            results.append(result_row)
            result_row = []
            offset = BEGIN


writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
writer.writerows(results)

Timestamp,       NOSE_X,       ..., MOUTH_RIGHT_Z
13:57:48.403076,  0.143783927, ...,  -0.238243863
13:57:48.403330, 0.1443544626, ..., -0.2033648193
...,                      ..., ...,           ...
...,                      ..., ...,           ...
13:57:48.416831, 0.2359642684, ..., -0.3811002076
13:57:48.417087, 0.2343592644, ..., -0.3764814734


I like the configurability/maintainability of this answer. Nicely done.
